# How to create template dependent member type

Tags: c++, templates, c++03

I am trying to cut down and simplify some horribly nested and over specialized templated C++ code.  To do so, I would like to be able to declare member type which is dependent on the templated type that the function or class has been instantiated with.

Take the following generic class template the resulting template specializations.  The type of 'a' depends on the instantiation type.

```
  template <typename Float> class A;

  template <>
    class A<double> {  
      double a;
    }
  };

  template <>
    class A<float> {  
      float a;
    }
  };


  template <>
    class A<short> {  
      float a;
    }
  };
```

The classes are identical except for the type of 'a', the mapping of template type to type of being double->double, float->float and short->float.  Is there a way simply encapsulated this mapping to allow to only write the class once?

I guess I would like to be write something like the following, but I have no idea if something this is possible.

```
  typedef double Float2<double>;
  typedef float Float2<float>;
  typedef float Float2<short>;

  template <typename Float>
    class A {  
      Float2<Float> a;
    }
  };
```

Note I am using C++03 and cannot use C++11 for this purpose (I think decltype may be of use here, but I'm not sure).

Answer (score 8):

There's no need to use `decltype`. You can just create a type trait and specialize it to provide the appropriate type mappings:

```
template<typename>
struct mapper;

template<>
struct mapper<double> {
    typedef double type;
};

template<>
struct mapper<float> {
    typedef float type;
};

template<>
struct mapper<short> {
    typedef float type;
};

template <typename Float> 
class A {
    typedef typename mapper<Float>::type float_type;

    float_type a;
};
```

Comment: Here is a writeup on C++ traits and use of templates from the Boost library in Dr. Dobbs Journal http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c-type-traits/184404270

Comment: And here is an article with a slightly different perspective that despite a few written English issues complements the Dr. Dobbs Journal article http://accu.org/index.php/journals/442

Comment: Traits a new and useful template technique http://www.cantrip.org/traits.html and Traits: the else if then of types http://erdani.com/publications/traits.html